# Using TFS Builds of DLL's

Tags: dll, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

In my mind i have a process I want todo with TFS, but in reality I dont seem to be able to work out how todo it.

Se we have a small team of developers, we build standard components (DLLS) that we use in lots of bits of software. When we make a change to one (StandardLib) for example we can get a build to generate in TFS, but is there a way in Visual Studio of linking our references to the latest build so we always use the latest version of the DLL, without having to build it locally on our PC's

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the build definition to create nuget packages for the dll files and publish the nuget packages to a feed. And then use nuget to manage the references in your project. When there is a new version of the dll files, you just need to run update package command to update the reference to the latest version.

Comment: I was reading about this, so I will give it a try, and report back.